# Java: How to update textArea from different class while a loop is running?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a little program to make reservations and I am stuck at how to update the `textArea` from a different class while I am doing some stuff in a loop ?

So for example I have this piece of code:

GUI class contains the very basic layout of GUI plus this method:

```
public class MyGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  public MyGUI()
  {
     ...
  }
  ....
  public void setResultArea(String text)
  {
    resultArea.append(text);
  }
}
```

Test class

```
public static void writeToTextArea()
{
    while(true)
    {
           if(message = "Hello World")
      ... 
      modify text area
    }
}
```

I look around but I couldn't find something related. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Swing is also single threaded, you should avoid running long running processes within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, as this will make the UI appear frozen, as it's unable to process new events in the Event Queue, including repaint events.  Equally, Swing is not thread safe and you should avoid updating the UI from outside the EDT. A common solution would be to use a `SwingWorker` which has `publish`/`process` methods to handle updating the UI, but allows you to executing long running process outside of the EDT

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Anybody else concerned about the assignment expression where there should be a boolean?

Comment: @BenKnoble Or the fact that it's not how `String`'s should be compared either...

Comment: @MadProgrammer good spot. I sometimes forget to check those

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, your test class needs a reference to your MyGUI class. There are various ways to give this reference:

- make a `setter` method in the test class which takes and stores a MyGUI.
- give the test class a constructor which takes and stores a MyGUI.

This is not considering best-practices of software design. That means, since I don't know the whole of your project, I can't comment on the best approach.

Once the test class "has" an instance of MyGUI, you can call the "setResultArea" method on it from the place you've written "modify text area".